# client receives weird characters from server, original message is not present at all

Tags: c

I have a normal client-server communication, just like Beej's guide insructs to do this stuff.

Server sends a string, but at recv in client, although value returned is ok (i.e. equal to the no of bytes sent from server), the characters received are totally weird, and value returned by strlen on received string is smaller than value returned by recv.

It seems really weird to me, so if you could give me a hint, it would be great.

This is part of server's code:

```
    s_gateway_server = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    memset( &server, 0, sizeof( server ) ); // asiguram padding-ul
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( is.port );
    inet_pton( AF_INET, is.ip, &server.sin_addr );

    status = connect( s_gateway_server, ( struct sockaddr* ) &server, sizeof( server ) );
    if( status == -1 )
    {
        printf( "ERROR\nNu te-ai putut conecta la server-ul %s :-(\n", is.ip );
        goto exit;
    }

    l = strlen( msg ) + 1;
    status = send( s_gateway_server, &msg, l, 0 );
    if( status == -1 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR\nla send catre server" );
        goto exit;
    }
    if( status < l )
    {
        //TODO trimite restul de pachet 
        printf( "ERROR\npachet ajuns incomplet la server\n" ); 
        goto exit;
    }

    printf( "Am trimis %d octeti: %s\n", status, msg );
```

And this is part of client's code:

```
void send_and_receive( int sock )
{
int status, ret;

while( 1 )
{
    char receivebuff[500];

    status = recv( sock, &receivebuff, 500, 0 );
    if( status == -1 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR\nla recv" );
        continue;
    }
    if( status == 0 )
        // connection closed
        break;
```

(did not paste all the function), and the function is called in main():

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
int s_server_gateway, conn_s_server_gateway, ret;
struct sockaddr_in gateway;
socklen_t length;

ret = parse_arg(argc, argv);
if( ret )
    return 1;

s_server_gateway = listen_to_clients();
if( s_server_gateway < 0 )
    return 2;

while( 1 )
{
    length = sizeof( gateway );
    conn_s_server_gateway = accept( s_server_gateway, ( struct sockaddr * ) &gateway, &length );

    if( conn_s_server_gateway == -1 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR\nla accept de la gateway" );
        continue;
    }

    if( !fork() )
    {
        close( s_server_gateway );

        send_and_receive( conn_s_server_gateway );

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        close( conn_s_server_gateway );

        continue;
    }
}

close( s_server_gateway ); 
return 0;
}


int listen_to_clients()
{
int s_server_gateway, optval, ret;
struct sockaddr_in server;

s_server_gateway = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
if( s_server_gateway == -1 )
{
    perror( "ERROR\nla deschidere socket" );
    return -1;
}

memset( &server, 0, sizeof( server ) ); // asiguram padding-ul
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( port );
inet_pton( AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr );

optval = 1;
ret = setsockopt( s_server_gateway, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof( int ) );
if( ret == -1 )
{
    perror( "ERROR\nla setsockopt" );
    close( s_server_gateway );
    return -2;
}

ret = bind( s_server_gateway, ( struct sockaddr * ) &server, sizeof( server ) );
if( ret == -1 )
{
    perror( "ERROR\nla bind" );
    close( s_server_gateway );
    return -3;
}

listen( s_server_gateway, BACKLOG );
if( ret == -1 )
{
    perror( "ERROR\nla listen" );
    close( s_server_gateway );
    return -4;
}

return s_server_gateway;
}
```

Comment: Seeing more of you client `while( 1 )` loop may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper parameter to `recv()`

```
char receivebuff[500];
// status = recv( sock, &receivebuff, 500, 0 )
status = recv( sock, receivebuff, 500, 0 ); // no &
// or better
status = recv( sock, receivebuff, sizeof(receivebuff), 0 );
```

Comment: Same here `status = send( s_gateway_server, &msg, l, 0 );`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. But I wonder, why didn't the compiler say anything? (I compiled with -Wall). What is even more weird is that I've used this before in simpler programs and it worked the way  wrote it the first time... thank you both,anyway!

Comment: @simm Not fully satisfied either.  Since I avoid the `&array`, it looked like the key unusual thing.  Still I wonder about the rest of the code when you determined "characters received are totally weird, and value returned by strlen on received string is smaller".